# Connecting a National Instruments device to an android phone

Tags: usb-peripherals

I'm attempting to connect a national instruments usb data aquisition device to a samsung galaxy s2 mobile phone. As far as I can tell the phone has a USB driver but no driver exists to run the national instruments device. Does anyone know where I would start in order to get one of these cards to talk to the phone?

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCtTaYfjydw) is [as close as](http://www.daq-software.com/SCCT%20brochure.pdf) I've come to finding a solution but it seems to require an external computer. I want to connect directly only using a phone.

This is in the early stage so I'm really looking for a starting point and then will update as/if I make progress.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to write an driver for the NI device that can be used on Android?  That's a large undertaking ... you would need to modify the ROM/OS to use the driver as well as developing the driver for the phone's architecture.  Development is off-topic here as well, you might have better luck on [SO].

Comment: Android 3.1 has a whole framework to make it easier to write a driver to allow an Android device to control a USB device. Previous Android versions  (such as the Android 2.3 your device comes with) only support being a USB slave, rather than a USB host device. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1-highlights.html#DeveloperApis

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use the USB port as a USB Host. This is not currently supported in android. The feature will be available on devices starting with [Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html). From what I took from the video, they are not using USB, they are communicating via TCP.

@GAThrawn, I honestly didn't just take your comment as an answer, I had mine in the form, but forgot to hit submit :)

Comment: No offence taken!

Comment: Thanks Mathew and GAThrawn. I'm no programming guru so it's good know that this is going to be a bit too big of an undertaking. Do you think smart phones will have USB Host support anytime soon or will this be reserved for tablet devices for the foreseeable future?

Comment: @Jamie "Ice Cream Sandwich" which is the rumoured name for the next version of Android will apparently be merging all of the phone features in Gingerbread with all of the tablet features in Honeycomb to make one OS that should have all of the good, new features of both, and should be available for both phones and tablets. As to how soon that will be released, and how soon individual devices will be updated... that's a whole different question.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. I'll kick back and wait for Ice Cream Sandwich.